# Java Recolor JProgressBar One Pixel Line

Tags: java, swing, colors, jprogressbar

[image]

As you can see at the JProgressBar above I modified it pretty much. But you most probably notice the white and light blue line in it. So now my question is how do I recolor it?

Answer (score 1):

Try remove the border with

```
JProgressBar jProgressBar1 = new ProgressBar();
jProgressBar1.setBorderPainted(false);
```

Assuming you are wanting to get rid of the blue/white line

Comment: Thanks but that also removed the red border. Any solution on how to remove the blue/white border only?

Comment: OK, you will have to create a new border and set it via the `setBorder()` method. Will update code in a sec

Comment: Sorry, thought this would be easier, have tried it myself but looks like you will have to change the Look and feel of the component. You can look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/) for a tutorial on this

Answer (score 1):

It is an old question but since I had the same problem just now, maybe it will help someone else. A (not very elegant) solution is to use a panel as container with a full-width progressbar and deactivate the progressbar border:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar();
bar.setBorderPainted(false);
bar.setStringPainted(true);

panel.add(bar);

Border border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Total progress...");
panel.setBorder(border);
```